# How safe is it for me to install Java on OS X 10.8 to use Bitcoin

Tags: client, java, safety

I want to use the Bitcoin client Multibit, but to do so I will need to install Java which over the past six months I've only heard bad things about.

So my question is: how safe is it for me to install Java on Mac OS X 10.8.3?

Answer (score 3):

You'd better ask it on the [Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), since apparently Bitcoin is not the core of this question, i.e. this could have happened with any software requiring Java.

That said, you could simply chose not to use Multibit: switch to another client, be it a desktop client or an online wallet.

Comment: Of I notice you already did ask it [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87784/how-safe-is-it-for-me-to-install-java-on-os-x-10-8 over there]. We can close this, then.

Comment: I am giving you vote up, but not enough credits to do it :(